# Keep the user logged in windows server

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, taskscheduler

I have a .bat file that I put it as a scheduled task.

The code needs to interact with the desktop so I had to check "run only when user is logged in' in the task scheduler.

But I want to run it at night. is there a way to keep the user logged in? or is there script that I can run just before to log the user automatically?

Comment: Yes, if you run the script as `administrator` and not running it with "run only when logged in"

Comment: I'm obliged to run it using  "run only when user is logged in"

Comment: Then it will not work unless you get a user to keep it logged in and not locked.

Comment: yes, i'm aware of that, so is there a way to keep it logged in ?

Comment: Short answer no, unless the user keeps it logged in and does not lock the pc. You can write a virus as well if you like :)

Comment: Thanks @GerhardBarnard the script that i'm running needs the user logged in otherwise it doesn't work.